# Notation f(x)<=O(g(x))

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, notation, rate-of-convergence

In writing a paper, I am using the notation $\beta_n\le O(n^{-3
})$ to mean any sequence converging to zero as fast as or even faster that $1/n^3$. 
Is this a standard notation?, and has anyone seen this in textbooks or papers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better notation is $\beta_n\in O(n^{-3})$, to emphasize the fact that $O(n^{-3})$ is the class of sequences converging to zero at least as fast as $n^{-3}$. Another usual notation is $\beta_n=O(n^{-3})$, but I've never seen $\le$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS   
but $O(n^{-3})$ does not include sequence with faster convergence rate of $1/n^3$, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. To explain the "class of", I have to tell you I was born in the Bourbaki period of french mathematical pedagogy :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS One more thing. which notation is preferred: $\beta_n=O(n^{-3})$ or $\beta_n \in O(n^{-3})$?

Comment: $\in$ is more rigorous, but I think you'll encounter more the notation $=$. The only thing not to forget is $O(f)$ represent a function $g$ such that (with some precautions) $\frac{g}{f}$ is bouded (or, if you have cancelation problems : $|g|\le M|f|$ for some constant $M$). So the "O"'s can't cancel, and bigger O's eat smaller ones...

Comment: @Sara: $\epsilon$ is preferable.